# My app works on API 19 but doesn't work on API 24

Tags: android, android-layout

My app is working good in both api 19 and api 24 except when saving the image , 
in api 19 when click to save button , the image saved into gallery, but when i click save in api 24 , it does't store any image and it doesn't perform toast message as api 19.
My point is: how can i modify my code without changing the whole project code to work well in api 24.

**signature.java**

```
  case R.id.action_download:
                File directory = Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                File file = new File(directory, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
                FileOutputStream out = null;
                Bitmap bitmap = signatureView.getSignatureBitmap();
                try {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    } else {
                        throw new FileNotFoundException();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (out != null) {
                            out.flush();
                            out.close();
                             //the bellow code does't work in api 24 ,but it       
                              works in api 19 to store image in galary.
                            if (bitmap != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Image saved successfully at " + file.getPath(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                                    new MyMediaScanner(this, file);
                                } else {
                                    ArrayList<String> toBeScanned = new ArrayList<String>();
                                    toBeScanned.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                                    String[] toBeScannedStr = new String[toBeScanned.size()];
                                    toBeScannedStr = toBeScanned.toArray(toBeScannedStr);
                                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, toBeScannedStr, null,
                                            null);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return true;
```

**gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kyanogen.signature"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation project(":signature-view")
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

}
```

Comment: Have you implemented permission model to request the permissions at runtime?

Comment: @Sagar yes  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: it works well in api 19 , but in api 24 the save button do not store image in gallary , in api 19 it store image in galary

Answer (score 0):

Add global variable:

```
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_ALL = 70;
```

Change your source code to this:

```
case R.id.action_download:
    if (obtainedPermissions(this, true, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_ALL)) {
        download();
    }
    return true;
```

Override the method:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_ALL) {
        if (obtainedPermissions(this, false, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_ALL)) {
            download();
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

And the methods for requesting permissions and downloading:

```
public static boolean obtainedPermissions(Activity activity, boolean request, int requestCode) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
        int hasPermissionReadExternalStorage = context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int hasPermissionWriteExternalStorage = context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (hasPermissionWriteExternalStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }

        if (hasPermissionReadExternalStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }

        if (permissions != null && !permissions.isEmpty()) {
            if (request) {
                String[] arrayPermission = permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayPermission, requestCode);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


private void download() {
    File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File file = new File(directory, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = signatureView.getSignatureBitmap();
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                 //the bellow code does't work in api 24 ,but it       
                  works in api 19 to store image in galary.
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Image saved successfully at " + file.getPath(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        new MyMediaScanner(this, file);
                    } else {
                        ArrayList<String> toBeScanned = new ArrayList<String>();
                        toBeScanned.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        String[] toBeScannedStr = new String[toBeScanned.size()];
                        toBeScannedStr = toBeScanned.toArray(toBeScannedStr);
                        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, toBeScannedStr, null,
                                null);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: brother should i change the min sdk and target sdk too?

Comment: Set it to the latest one, the min should be even 20 or less depending on the other features of your project. The target could be 27.

Comment: where should i pest  onRequestPermissionsResult method?

Comment: Wherever into your class (probably this class extends Activity or AppCompatActivity ...), where you have your source code above.

Comment: the app works fine in api 19 , but in api 24 when click save the app is stopped same as before.

Comment: Send me your source code (my profile). I will fix it and post solution.

Comment: better to have your email brother?

Comment: am new here so i dont know how to sened the source code brother.

Comment: brother can i send source code throught your email brother

Comment: So email - jan.tursky@gmail.com